# ANLTR 4 (Java) catch parser errors/expections for test purposes

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, junit5

I'm working on an ANTLR-Parser and now am writing tests for the parser.

I already found a way to "positive"- test the parser, but now also want to test that the parser also fails when supplied with a bad input (negative test?).

What **i would like** is a way to use JUnits `Assertions.assertThrows()` to for example a `NoViableAltException` or any of the other exceptions thrown by the parser.

I've already looked at the `ANTLRErrorListener` and its implementations, but haven't a found solution there.

This is my test case so far:

```
@Test
    public void test_short_negative() {

        String[] string_values = new String[]{"{", "<EOF>"};
        int[] id_values = new int[]{MyLexer.CBRACKET_OPEN, MyLexer.EOF};

        ArrayList<TestToken> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < id_values.length; i++) tokens.add(new TestToken(string_values[i], id_values[i]));

        ListTokenSource source = new ListTokenSource(tokens);
        for(TestToken t: tokens) t.setTokenSource(source);

        TestErrorListener errorListener = new TestErrorListener(true);
        MyParser pars = createParser(new ListTokenSource(tokens), errorListener);
        pars.stmt_block();
    }
```

---

```
public class TestErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {
    private boolean hadError = false;
    private TestToken lastOffendingSymbol;

    private boolean doPrint;

    public TestErrorListener(boolean doPrint){
        this.doPrint = doPrint;
    }

    public boolean hadError() {
        return hadError;
    }

    public TestToken getLastOffendingSymbol() {
        return lastOffendingSymbol;
    }

    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        if(doPrint) System.out.println("Syntax error at " + line + ":" + charPositionInLine + ". Symbol: '" + ((TestToken) offendingSymbol).getText() + "' could not be parsed.");
        hadError = true;
        lastOffendingSymbol = (TestToken) offendingSymbol;
    }

    @Override
    public void reportAmbiguity(Parser recognizer, DFA dfa, int startIndex, int stopIndex, boolean exact, BitSet ambigAlts, ATNConfigSet configs) {
        if(doPrint) System.out.println("Ambiguity found at [" + startIndex + ":" + stopIndex + "]!");
    }


}
```

---

**Library versions :**

- **ANTLR4**: 4.7.2
- **JUnit**: 5.5.0-m1

---

All help is appreciated ^^

Comment: Does your `TestErrorListener ` throw an exception on a syntax error? If it does, all you need is to execute `pars.stmt_block();` in conjunction with `assertThrows()`

Comment: @PavelSmirnov No it doesn't. I've added my code for the `TestErrorListener` to the question above. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also want to test that the parser also fails when supplied with a bad input

It's quite not clear what you mean by "fails" in this context, but I assume that you mean "how do I know a syntax error has occured?". Because ANTLR parser can recover from some syntax errors, skip a few tokens and continue parsing.

Each time a syntax error is encountered, the `syntaxError()` method of your `TestErrorListener` is invoked.

According to your sample code, you set the `hadError` flag to true each time an error occurs, which means, after parsing is done, you can test this flag is true, or false, regarding your input tokens.

Also, you can make ANTLR throw exceptions immediately and stop parsing whenever an error occured by providing an error handler, i.e.:

```
pars.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());
```

From now on, your parser will be throwing `ParseCancellationException`. Catching it and using `getCause()` method you can get the real cause that made the parser stop, including `NoViableAltException`.

In the latter case, all you have to do is to run your `pars.stmt_block();` in conjunction with `assertThrows()` and check that `ParseCancellationException` is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for. Just one small question is there any already implemented Listener/ErrorStrategy that keeps track of all errors?
I want to build an editor with the parser and need that for checking the syntax.

Comment: No, there are only two implementations of [ANTLRErrorStrategy](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorStrategy.html) interface, `BailErrorStrategy` and `DefaultErrorStrategy`. If you want to track syntax errors, you have to implement your own ErrorListener and apply an action each time `syntaxError()` is invoked.